# Favorite Tags - Remembering of "Tab"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have several favorite tags, defined on my stackoverflow account.

At one point I switched to the *featured* tab to see questions with bounties. From that point on the click on *any* tag lead to the *featured* page. For a couple of  Weeks I thought that this has been changed so I stopped using the tags, cause usually there are no questions with bounties for my favorite tags.

Meanwhile I figured out, that the "Tagged Questions" Page remembers the last active tab - but independent of the actual tag.

From a usability point of view (limited to my opinion ofc.) I would change that behavior:

- Either remember the "state" as a pair of **tag** and **tab** (rather than just **tab**)

  - i.e. `php-featured`, `ruby-newest`, `regex-frequent`, `jsf-unanswered`
- Or don't remember the tab and show the `newest` tab by default.

Ofc, *now* I know it - but If that behavior has successfully confused me as a regular visitor - what about all the new and infrequent users?

---

The main confusion might origin from the fact that, whenever I select a **tag** and beeing forwarded to the previously selected **tab**, while the **tag** has no questions of that type - the whole tab is **not** visible, so it is pretty much not *clear*, *why* there are no results:

[image]

Yes, the text pretty much *contains* the information I need to know - but since there is **no** featured tab visible, (so obviously it's not highlighted) - I didn't notice that I need to switch tabs *over there*

---

Compare with this view: Here it is *clear* that i *could* switch the tab (tab **is** visible **and** marked active):

[image]

Comment: And what about those users who *want* to see the featured tab when they return? I don't see anything that needs to be changed; you only need it to happen once, you figure out how to fix it, and you're done. It's a matter of learning how to use the site, just like everything else here. (I added the feature-request tag, as that's what this is; if you get downvotes on the question, it's related to votes on the usability of the feature change and not the quality of your question.)

Comment: It is a pretty silly navigation bug that they don't know how to fix, it seems.  Other than telling you that you are doing it wrong, added later, before that it was just empty.  You didn't of course.  Been around for a long time, years.  Grotty code, programmers know what that looks like :)  But well compensated.

Comment: I've found this particularly annoying ever since I joined SO. I generally have multiple **browser** tabs open, each on a different "tagged questions" SO page (eg one for Python, one for PyQt). If I switch one of these to the "featured" SO tab, and refresh the others, they also go to the "featured" tab. I thus resort to making sure I always have an explicit `?sort=newest` (or similar) in the URLs of the browser tabs I have open. Of course if I navigate away from this page, and return via a tag on a question, that part of the URL goes away! rinse-repeat.

Comment: I just encountered this and was writing up a question. This madness has to end! There is no reason for tab stickiness from tag to tag.